# mysql password encrypt in vb6 app

Tags: mysql, vb6, passwords

I have a VB6 application that connects to a MySQL DB. The username and the password are in the source code. The problem is that when I open the .exe file in a hex editor the username and the password are both visible.

Can you suggest a solution so that the username and the password would be no longer visible? 
Thanks

Comment: That's fundamentally impossible.  If the user can run your app, he can see how your app connects.  You need some kind of user authentication.  What are you trying to defend against?

Comment: You may want to hide the DB behind a web service (although you'll still need user authentication).

Comment: I simply don't want my DB username and password to be visible so anyone could access my data.

Comment: If they can access your data through your app, they can also access it directly.  There is no direct way around that; you can either make it slightly harder or use actual authentication.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as those credentials are in your application, someone with a little knowledge can find and read them.

If you encrypt that information, you'll need to decrypt it at some point. So you'll either need the decryption key in the app - so people can read it too, rendering the whole thing moot - or you'll be decrypting server-side - in which case anyone else could just send the encrypted credentials as well.

So here's a tip: don't base the security of your application on having some secret buried within the code. You'll just be presenting script kiddies with an interesting challenge.

Answer (score 1):

You really need a middle tier.

Wherever practical you want to avoid sharing the database credentials with clients.  Ideally you don't even want firewalls to allow database connections from outside.

Client/server DBMS connection protocols are not optimal for use across the Internet anyway.

These are all reasons why the "web service" concept came about, and was being used even before the phrase had been coined.

Of course that still leaves you with the need for credentials at the client.  I'd handle this by storing them externally so that they can be updated.  You might also want to use two stages of decryption in your programs so that you can divide the process up, making it harder to reverse engineer from decompiled/disassembled code.  Do one stage early in initialization and the other later, or do stage two just prior to making your connection.